# AWS profile with gitlab -ci

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab-ci

We are using git-lab as our repo and decided to go with gitlab ci. we are using server-less framework to deploy our code on AWS. I want to integrate AWS profiles to Gitlab so that it can call the specific profile and enter into the AWS account specified. I have tried hard-coding the variables but if i have to enter using a different profile for the Deployment, i need to change all the gitlab-ci files as am having more than 100 repos.

Any way to configure the aws profiles in gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

Basically my git-lab-CI jobs runs on Docker. so i created a docker image with all the needed prerequisites needed for my Deployment and now my runtime is same as my Local machine with AWS-CLI installed and i can use my AWS profiles for the deployment in the serverless files